# How to select last row to the top but still let the other row in order from the first to last

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I want to select some row using query where it shows the last row at the top but still let the other row appears in order. For example :
If I got something like this

```html
<table border="1px">
      <tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Month of Birth</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>January</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>February</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Jane</td><td>Doe</td><td>March</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Danny</td><td>Prince</td><td>April</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Then I would like to show something like this :

```html
<table border="1px">
      <tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Month of Birth</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Danny</td><td>Prince</td><td>April</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>January</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>February</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Jane</td><td>Doe</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Is it possible to do that in 1 query? If it's possible, how?
I appreciate any kind of help, thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible. Provide table DDL and sample data insert  if more details needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @tbMos table(Mname nvarchar(50),num int)
insert into @tbMos
select 'January',1 union all
select 'February',2 union all
select 'March',3 union all
select 'April',4 union all
select 'May',5 union all
select 'June',6 union all
select 'July',7 union all
select 'August',8 union all
select 'September',9 union all
select 'October',10 union all
select 'November',11 union all
select 'December',12

declare @tb table(Firstname nvarchar(50),Lastname nvarchar(50),[MonthName] nvarchar(50))
Insert into @tb
select 'Jill','Smith','January' union all
select 'Eve','Jackson','February' union all
select 'Jane','Doe','March' union all
select 'Danny','Prince','April'

declare @LastMname varchar(50)
select top 1 @LastMname = [Monthname] from @tb order by [Monthname]

;with cte as(
  select firstname,lastname,[monthname],mname,num from
(select * from
(select * from @tb where [monthname] <>@LastMname ) as a) as a
left join  
(select * from @tbmos) as b on 
a.[monthname] = b.mname 
)

select firstname,lastname,[monthname] from
(select * from cte
union all
select *,'lastmname',0 from
(select top 1 * from @tb order by [Monthname]) as a) as a
order by num
```

result:

```
Danny   Prince  April
Jill    Smith   January
Eve     Jackson February
Jane    Doe     March
```

Comment: This will get the last month first according to your sample from above and followed by the remaining month in ascending order. from Jan. to Dec.

Answer (score 0):

Demo

```
create table tt (
    x int,
    );

insert tt(x) 
values (1),(20),(17),(8);

select x 
from( 
    select x, case Row_number() over(order by x DESC) when 1 then 2147483647 -- max int
       else Row_number() over(order by x DESC) end rn
    from tt
    ) t
order by rn DESC;
```